# Get a list of all scripts and their paths which are run as cron job

Tags: scripts, cron, logs, anacron

I am looking for some scripts or a terminal command to list all the active scripts (preferably with their paths), which run on a periodic basis by cron, cron.daily and/or anacron. I am not looking for a filter for a specific time-period of the script and need all the scripts listed, (however some administrators may want this kind of filter).

**Purpose:** To document all scripts running periodically, so that debugging or fault check, updating and transferring to a newer system is easy and efficient.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you want. 
I found this answer some time ago on some stackexchange and I use it on one server.

```
for user in $(cut -f1 -d: /etc/passwd); do echo $user; crontab -u $user -l; done
```

This will list all crontabs for all users.

Comment: Did it work? If so I would be glad if you mark my answer as correct.

Comment: Well its just prints the current user's full cron file and for other users it says use as `-u`. So it is not what I wanted !

Comment: Try to run it as root. That should do the trick. Otherwise could you please specify what you want?

Comment: I do not want output of the cron file. What I want is specifically the list of shell scripts set by user as cron-jobs.

Comment: But isn't that the content of the crontabs? The user writes his script into the crontab and the cron runs the script.

Comment: Actually, no. Cron run many other system processes, which are not set by user but by the kernel/OS. This list is big.

Comment: I had asked  this question on Unix&Linux SE, and got really useful answer. Pls check. [Scripts as cron-job](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/285367/get-a-list-of-all-scripts-and-their-paths-which-are-run-as-cron-job)

Answer (score 0):

As for anything you find on internet you should not run without understanding but the following will get the filenames and display paths for the scripts run in the `cron.hourly`/`cron.daily`/`cron.monthly` folders... (CentOS in my case)

```
cd /etc/cron.hourly/&&for i in $(ls);do find `pwd` -name $i;done&&cd /etc/cron.daily/&&for i in $(ls);do find `pwd` -name $i;done&&cd /etc/cron.weekly/&&for i in $(ls);do find `pwd` -name $i;done&&cd /etc/cron.monthly/&&for i in $(ls);do find `pwd` -name $i;done
```

basically multiple versions of this:

```
cd /etc/cron.hourly/&&for i in $(ls);do find 'pwd' -name $i;done
```

Change to directory then for each filename in `ls` find and display the path

EDIT: for coder people who like structure... same thing as a function:

```
function AllTheCrons {
    cd /etc/cron.hourly/
    for i in $(ls);
        do
            find `pwd` -name $i;
        done;
    cd /etc/cron.daily/
    for i in $(ls);
        do
            find `pwd` -name $i;
        done;
    cd /etc/cron.weekly/
    for i in $(ls);
        do
            find `pwd` -name $i;
        done;
    cd /etc/cron.monthly/
    for i in $(ls);
        do
            find `pwd` -name $i;
        done;
}
```

then run:

```
AllTheCrons
```

Comment: To run it with better understanding… Could you format the code into several lines and indent them?

Comment: if i did that it wouldn't run :) thats why i have single line posted seperate and explained.

Comment: Actually guess could run.

Comment: I suck at formatting. cheers @Melebius

Comment: Thanks. I personally would put the code (yes, the formatted one) in a dedicated script file. And when I see the structure, there could be one outer `for`, looping over the four directories. In that case, the one-liner could be shorter. :-)

Comment: Saw that too but thought that introduces complexity and edge cases, Also completely ignores crontab's but it'll list the scripts.